# is it possible to find the sequence of the incoming edges in each node from the adjacency list?

Tags: python, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

currently I am working with the directed acyclic graph and using the longest path in each node and I have a question with seeing the sequence of incoming edges to each node. for example, refer to this graph

[image]

```
node 1 : 0 (0 means no incoming edge)
node 2 : 2 (2 means the max of the sequence of edges in node 2 that defined from the maximum path in node 2 according to it has 3 paths from 1->2, 3->2 and 1->3->2 and the longest path is 1->3->2 then the max sequence is 2)
node 3 : 1 (1 means the sequence from 1->3)
node 4 : 3 (3 means the max of the sequence of edges in node 4 that defined from the maximum path in node 4 according to it has 3 paths from 1->2->4, 1->3->4, and 1->3->2->4 and the longest path is 1->3->2->4 then the max sequence is 3)
```

at first, I consider to the counting incoming edge but if I use that way, the result will be

```
node 1 : 0
node 2 : 2
node 3 : 1
node 4 : 3
```

which is not match with my purpose
any recommended source, suggestion, and paper that I need to study more??

thank you in advance

Comment: If you already have the longest path from each node (e.g. `paths = [[1, 3, 2, 4], [2, 4], [3, 2, 4], [4]]`) then you can take the greatest index of each vertex in each list. `[max(x.index(i) if i in x else 0 for x in paths) for i in range(1, len(paths) + 1)]`. However I'm not sure if this works in every single case.

Comment: hello, thank you for your reply and the result is ran well but could you please explain more how it works?, I am quite confusing this condition "x.index(i) if i in x else 0 for x in paths"